# errors occur when using cl cmd to generate dll file?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

Today, I used cl cmd which is vs 2010 attached to compile a demo to gain a dll file. I written a file, its content as follow:

```
CALL "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
cl /LD getKLineForKdb.cpp getKLineForKdb.def TDB_API_Windows_v2.lib q.lib
```

and saved it as comprun.bat. When I used cmd to run it, some error messages occurred:

```
d:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(323) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\wingdi.h(4562) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '->'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\wingdi.h(4563) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '->'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\mmsystem.h(770) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\mmsystem.h(770) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\mmsystem.h(770) : warning C4183: 'waveformat_tag': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'.
```

Does anyone face this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Please include all the output (including your `.cpp` file that generates them as you may have a compilation error inside) not just the error/warning lines. Also for this kind of actions (building some `.c`/`.cpp` sources into an app/dll) [Windows Makefiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha(v=vs.100).aspx) or [Visual Studio Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfzh36t7(v=vs.100).aspx) should be used.

Comment: @CristiFati, I solved it just by adjusted the included file. Also, Thanks a lot.

Comment: `adjusted the include file`? As in modified one of the system include files? That's not good.